# Equivalent of "catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" with catkin build?

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a release configuration with optimizations and no debugging symbols, I can use the Release build type:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Is there an equivalent command line with catkin build?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310112/equivalent-of-%22catkin_make--dcmake_build_type=release%22-with-catkin-build?/) by [fabriceN](https://answers.ros.org/users/31629/fabricen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2018-12-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the following:

```
catkin config --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

EDIT: you might want to look into [the docs](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_config.html).

RE single package: I think that is simply done by `catkin build <package you want to optimize>` with the flag and removing the CMake flag when building the others. Also note that you should comment under my answer, not post a new answer...and possibly accept the answer if I solved your issue.

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2018-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fabriceN](https://answers.ros.org/users/31629/fabricen/) on 2018-12-06**:
@aPonza thank you very much, it works and do you know if it is possible to optimize a package only?

**Comment by [fabriceN](https://answers.ros.org/users/31629/fabricen/) on 2018-12-06**:
@aPonza yes I made a mistake when I replied ... Thanks again and you fully answered my question actually